# autoLink for map not working

Tags: android, android-widget

I have the following TextView in my XML layout file:-

```
<TextView  
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:text="@string/autolink_test"
       android:autoLink="all"
/>
```

The string autolink_test contains a phone number, an email address, a website address and a physical geographical address.

While the first three are showing up correctly as clickable autolinks, the address does not. Only the zipcode part shows up as an autolink... and that too as a phone number! (When I click it, the phone dialer starts up with that number).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you tell us what String "autolink_test" is; hard to diagnose otherwise.

Comment: Daniel,

Thanks for the comment. Trying to answer it helped me figure out the problem!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK, I figured out what was causing the problem. Just thought I will leave the answer here in case someone else runs into the same problem.

If the street address is not properly capitalized, it is not read properly as the address!

Here is my XML autolink_test string:

```
<string name="autolink_test">Name: New York Times \n
   Email: public@nytimes.com \n
   Phone: 212-556-7652 \n
   Address: 620 Eighth Avenue New York, NY 10018  \n
   Address: 620 Eighth avenue New York, NY 10018  \n
   Website: http://www.nytimes.com
</string>
```

The first address shows up correctly as an autolink.
The second one (with a small 'a' in 'avenue') does not show up correctly.

This seems a little strange to me as the google maps website certainly doesn't care about such niceties.

Anyways, so here it is :-)

Comment: I dug a little deeper and found the actual "`isThisAnAddress`" code:
[WebKit source called via JNI](http://source-android.frandroid.com/external/webkit/Source/WebKit/android/nav/CacheBuilder.cpp), the method name is `CacheBuilder::FindAddress`.
At `case FIND_STREET:` the `longStreetNames` array is being indexed by `letter -= 'A'`, hence no support for lowercase.

Comment: This will also happen if you don't specify street/lane/address/etc as part of the address.

Comment: Same problem when boulevard is used. Won't work with Blvd

Answer (score 12):

Alternative to it, in case if **autolink** doesn't work

Add links to your texview . Get it underline as folows :

```
SpannableString spanStr = new SpannableString(buf.toString());
spanStr.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, spanStr.length(), 0);
iTextView.setText(spanStr);
```

Use the following code to open it with map app on click as follows :

```
Intent geoIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q="
                                +iTextView.getText().toString()));
startActivity(geoIntent);
```

Comment: I decided to use this approach because autolink seems so "touchy" in terms of what text is and isn't acceptable, (as the op states, "This seems a little strange to me as the google maps website certainly doesn't care about such niceties.") Aside from case sensitivity, I noticed that leaving out "Street", "Avenue", etc. also caused a "rejection" of input.