# Android Text View Map Address

Tags: android, textview

In Text View, i find a XML attribute 'autoLink'. We can assign a value 'map' to match map address. However, i don't know what is map address. Can anyone give me an example?

Thank.

Comment: Map will try to match a location link. On clicking will open google maps. You can find example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624649/autolink-for-map-not-working

Comment: see this link http://android-er.blogspot.com/2009/08/exercise-autolink-and-layout-change.html
it will be more usefull